# Firefox saved logins gone on ubuntu

Tags: login, firefox, password

I tried to copy over my firefox profile from my windows 10 machine to my ubuntu lapotp. Everything works just fine except for the saved passwords & logins. History and cookies seem to be still there, but my passwords are gone. I tried to use the same profile on another windows 10 machine and it worked just fine. Is there any way to get my passwords back on ubuntu?

Comment: Check `about:preferences?entrypoint=menupanel#sync` in Firefox address bar and make sure that Logins is selected in Sync Settings.

Comment: I am not using that feature. I never have. It works on all my Windows 10 machines, but not on my linux machines. I copied the profile folder itself. I do not have a firefox account. The passwords are on my computer but I cannot access them.

Comment: You might want to consider doing an account then.  Window 10 can synchronize settings between systems as long as you are using the same account on them.  Ubuntu doesn't sync with Windows 10 automatically, so you can either copy your profiles manually see https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1189644 or setup an account

Comment: Kindly see if [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1161538) can help.

Answer (score 0):

`about:logins` page has option to exports personal logins. Logins & passwords are saved as plain text, so make sure to deal with them attentively.
Starting with Firefox v80 (Nightly) you may import saved logins.