# Troubleshooting Firefox

Tags: firefox

## BACKGROUND

I am suddenly unable to access websites from Firefox 68.0 on 16.04.

1. Chromium is able to access websites as the local router.
2. Firefox is not able elicit a response from the router's LAN IP address.
3. `ping -c 3 yahoo.com` functions as expected from command line

## QUESTIONS

What additional tests can be performed to find the root cause of the problem?

Can one conclude the problem is isolated to Firefox?

## UPDATES

[image]

Comment: Did you check Network Settings under Firefox preferences to make sure no proxy is in use?

Comment: @Raffa  Good question:  I have posted settings and believe there is no proxy.

Comment: No proxy, true. Firefox uses DNS Prefetching. According to the following link it can cause connectivity issues and can be disabled for troubleshooting https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-cant-load-websites-other-browsers-can

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Firefox's configuration files located under `.mozilla/firefox/` in the user's home directory get corrupted due to force kill Firefox (eg. system crash, system reboot or shutdown while browser tabs are open). This can sometimes happen during Firefox or system upgrades.

---

**Fix Firefox:**

You can make Firefox build new fresh configuration if you rename/delete the current configuration directory. **Be warned you will loose all your plugins, bookmarks, saved site logins ...etc. and you will end up with a new default fresh copy of Firefox**. To try this:

1. Close Firefox browser.
2. Back up your current Firefox configuration directory. Run the following in the terminal:

   `cp -r ~/.mozilla/firefox/ ~/.mozilla/firefox_old/`
3. Delete your current Firefox configuration directory. Run the following in the terminal:

   `rm -r ~/.mozilla/firefox/`
4. Start Firefox browser. A new `.mozilla/firefox/` directory will be automatically created with fresh configuration files in it.
5. Try Firefox now and see if it works again.

---

**Rescue data:**

If all goes well and Firefox is working again and **you wish to restore your important data to the new configuration directory**, please follow the steps below:

1. Close Firefox browser.
2. Run the following command in the terminal:

`cp ~/.mozilla/firefox_old/*default/{logins.json,key3.db,key4.db,places.sqlite,cookies.sqlite,formhistory.sqlite,permissions.sqlite,content-prefs.sqlite} ~/.mozilla/firefox/*default/`

3. Start Firefox browser. This should restore your site logins, passwords, bookmarks, form data and cookies. Please read [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Transferring_data_to_a_new_profile_-_Firefox)

---

**Plan B:**

If you decide to go back to your old Firefox configuration, Please follow the instructions below:

1. Close Firefox browser.
2. Delete your new Firefox configuration directory. Run the following in the terminal:

   `rm -r ~/.mozilla/firefox/`
3. Restore your old Firefox configuration directory. Run the following in the terminal:

   `cp -r ~/.mozilla/firefox_old/ ~/.mozilla/firefox/`
4. Start Firefox browser. You are now back to your old Firefox configuration. Exactly as it was before you attempt to fix it using [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1161538/968501).
5. If all goes well, clean up and remove the back up created during this process. Run the following in the terminal:

   `rm -r ~/.mozilla/firefox_old/`

Comment: @gatorback I added extra instructions on how to restore old data. Please have a look.