# new Firefox 70.0 update breaks Firefox

Tags: firefox, 19.04

I just performed a Software Update where Firefox was updated to version 70.0. Now various web sites don't load correctly... like `Credit Karma` and `Netflix`. Amongst other problems, clicking links on pages doesn't take you to the desired web page location.

If I open a private window, and visit those same two web sites, it all seems to work again.

I've tried starting in safe mode, where all of my add-ons were disabled, but with no improvement.

I've tried disabling these sites from the new "blocking social media trackers" feature, but with no improvement.

Anybody else having Firefox 70.0 problems, and seen this problem? Is there a fix/workaround?

**Update #1:**

Selecting a different user profile also fixes the problem. I'm working on which particular item is causing the problem.

**Update #2:**

pending possible fix...

- in Firefox, go to `about:profiles`
- note which profile is the current, in use profile
- for the `Root Directory` click the `Open Directory` button
- quit Firefox
- move the `storage` and <strike>`weave`</strike> folders out to another location
- restart Firefox, it'll rebuild these two folders
- try the web site that was giving you problems and see if it's working now
- <strike>quit Firefox</strike>
- move the newly created `storage` and `weave` folders to the trash
- move the original `storage` and `weave` folders back to their original location
- restart Firefox
- confirm that the problem web site still works

**Update #3:**

Updated procedure documented in my answer, shown below.

Comment: I am wondering if you have encountered the 'dedicated profile per installation' issue that has been a problem for the past few releases of Firefox? Have a look in `about:profiles` to see if you have been shifted to a 'vanilla' profile...

Comment: The renegade profile will be called: 'Profile: default-release'....

Comment: @andrew.46 I don't have such a profile. Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/a/1161538/968501

Comment: Seeing this after the 70.0 upgrade on Ubuntu! Was working fine before the latest update. I am going to log-out and check again, and hope that that fixes the problem.

Comment: This [article in GHacks](https://www.ghacks.net/2019/10/29/firefox-70-not-loading-some-pages-or-elements-here-is-a-fix/) seems to deal with your problem.

Comment: @user68186 Thanks for the information. Unfortunately it describes a method to disable the new "storage" feature in Firefox 70.0. I don't recommend that. Please see my answer below for what I believe is a better fix.

Comment: @Raffa Thanks for the information. My suggested fix doesn't require rebuilding Firefox profiles, and I believe is a much simpler fix. Please see my answer, below.

Comment: Fix supposedly out today: https://www.ghacks.net/2019/11/01/mozilla-firefox-70-0-1-release-information/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recently updated Firefox 70.0 has problems rendering many web sites. Clicking on links sometimes doesn't take you to the desired web location. This has to do with a new Firefox design having to do with "storage".

After much testing, I've come up with this solution...

- in `Firefox` 70.0, go to `about:profiles`
- note which profile is the current, in use, profile
- for the `Root Directory` click the `Open Directory` button
- quit `Firefox`
- move the `storage` folder out to another location
- restart `Firefox`, it'll rebuild this folder automatically
- try the web site that was giving you problems and see if it's working now

**Update #1:**

Pending release of Firefox 70.0.1 is also supposed to resolve the problem.