# Firefox 70.0 does not load some website pages completely. Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: firefox

I am using Ubuntu/Firefox for several years.
Now some pages do not load completery, progress icon moves permanently.
Examples:  "pCloud.com" "facebook.com" "Webmin/File Manager" and others
Other pages of those websites load normally.
I tried restart with plugins disables but nothing changed.
Same webpages load okay with Chrome.

> about:config
>   dom.storage.next_gen
>   Set the preference to False

results in
[image]

According to [this](https://www.ghacks.net/2019/10/29/firefox-70-not-loading-some-pages-or-elements-here-is-a-fix/?_m=3n%2E0038%2E2382%2Ezd0ao07qk6%2E2hn2) creating a new profile would solve the entire issue.       I don't want to create a new profile.
At least those pages are loading normally now.

Comment: I can't reproduce it.

Comment: I don't know what happened.  I didn't add or change add ons, only have a few.
Also restarted. I don't know what to do or what to check

Comment: Might be a bug in Firefox 70.0 due to recent performance optimizations. Google for "Firefox 70 dynamic javascript" to learn more. https://www.ghacks.net/2019/10/29/firefox-70-not-loading-some-pages-or-elements-here-is-a-fix/

Comment: @lumbric "Bad: Our test logic is broken, please copy and paste the contents of 'Debug Info' below and anything in the devtools console and send to :asuth. (unexpectedBreakage)"  What does "send to :asuth" mean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [new Firefox 70.0 update breaks Firefox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1183632/new-firefox-70-0-update-breaks-firefox)

Comment: That's what I performed then "LocalStorage" became green but the others remain in red.  That's why I mentioned the option to create a new profile