# Firefox gmail problem

Tags: firefox, chromium, gmail

I have been using Firefox for several years, partly because it has been the default browser for Ubuntu. Yesterday, for some reason, the Gmail page on my Firefox browser is completely blank -- no messages or logos, just empty white space. Oddly, all the other Google items, such as calendar or maps work fine.

If I use Chromium, the other browser I have installed on my machine, Gmail works just as it always has. But even if I copy the URL from the Gmail tab in Chromium to the Gmail tab in Firefox, it doesn't display. Did a recent Ubuntu update have anything that would alter the way Gmail works?

I use Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS. I'm not sure how to determine what version of Gmail, but whenever anything tries to update, I do that, so it's probably the latest current version.

Comment: Close Firefox and start it in safe mode with `firefox --safe`. Does it work? That mode starts firefox with extensions disabled.

Comment: _I'm not sure how to determine what version of Gmail..._ Gmail isn't an app, so it does not have a version number as Firefox, Chrome, and Chromium have.

Comment: What version Firefox? 70.0? If so, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1183632/new-firefox-70-0-update-breaks-firefox. Please remember to vote for my answer if it solves your problem. Thanks!