# stubborn Firefox on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS Gnome

Tags: firefox, workspaces

I have been using Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS, with workspaces stacked vertically for some years.
I like to open Firefox in the top workspace, but some two weeks ago this program started to behave oddly just after boot.
It stubbornly opens in the third workspace from the top, even though I have the first one open.
I always have to move it to the first workspace, but when I boot again and start Firefox, there it goes to the third one again.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: If this is related to Firefox configuration changes, you could try [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1161538/968501)

Comment: Ok. Since you were the only one to respond, I have done what you suggested.
The problem has been solved.
However, every previous configuration has been lost, even after doing the procedures described in the “Rescue Data” section.
I’ll leave it with the problem fixed and will try to remember the rest.
Thank you!

Comment: Do plan b in the linked answer to restore your settings while Firefox is closed then search for  the file `xulstore.json` in your Firefox profile by running `find ~/.mozilla/firefox/ -type f -name "xulstore.json"` then delete it and start Firefox.

Comment: Thanks!
It’s working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox has a config "widget.disable-workspace-management" that defaults to "false", i.e., Firefox does do some workspace management by default. Setting it to "true" fixes this problem for me. Here are the steps:

1. Open Firefox.
2. In the address bar (the place where you usually type in a URL), enter "about:config".
3. You might need to accept a warning about changing preferences.
4. In the "Search preference name" field, either put in the whole config name mentioned above, or just put in "workspace".
5. In the result that comes up, widget.disable-workspace-management, it should show "false" by default. To toggle to "true", click on the double-arrow icon on the far right of the preference (if you hover over it, the status tip will say "Toggle".
6. There is no "save" you need to do. Your change applies immediately.

If you prefer, you can change this preference on the command line (this is nice if you use a setup script that sets up your applications how you like them when you do a fresh install of your operating system). To do this:

1. Make sure no instance of Firefox is running (otherwise the change could be overwritten).
2. Find the prefs.js file that corresponds to your Firefox profile. One way to find it is to first do `sudo updatedb` and then `locate -b "\prefs.js"`. In the results, pick the one that looks like it corresponds to your profile. For me, the correct file is the following: `~/.mozilla/firefox/main/prefs.js`.
3. Then, you can append the config into that file. Using the filename above, the command would be the following:

   `echo 'user_pref("widget.disable-workspace-management", true);' >> mozilla/firefox/main/prefs.js`

Here is an attempt at a fully automated command. It may or may not work for you:

```
if pgrep -x "firefox" > /dev/null; then
    echo "ERROR: Should not modify config while Firefox is running." >&2
    echo "Please exit all Firefox instances and try again." >&2
else
  for d in ~/.mozilla/firefox/*; do
    if [ -e "${d}/prefs.js" ]; then
      echo 'user_pref("widget.disable-workspace-management", true);' >> "${d}/prefs.js"
    fi
  done
fi
```

I learned about this config value from "jamiemint" on his reply [here](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=1959750&sid=18a53bfcea37b8c0cec724f8506b5205#p1959750). Thank you jamiemint!

Comment: Thank you, scottkosty. This seems to be working.
I’ll mark this as “solved”.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox window size and location is saved in a file called `xulstore.json` in your Firefox profile directory.

To reset it find the file by running ( **close Firefox first** ):

```
find ~/.mozilla/firefox/ -type f -name "xulstore.json"
```

Then rename or delete the file or, alternatively, run the following command which will rename the file for you:

```
find ~/.mozilla/firefox/ -type f -name "xulstore.json" -exec mv {} {}.old \;
```

Then start Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I did what @Raffa suggested, and it worked… for a few days.
Now, for no apparent reason, Firefox is opening in the last (fourth) workplace.
Only Firefox does this. Other programs open correctly in the active workspace.
I’m afraid that the solution proposed did not work.
A sign that something is not quite right is that, when it opens in the wrong workspace, it takes much longer than it did to open in the active workspace.
Any other solutions for this puzzle?

Comment: If your problem first occurred when going from Firefox 74 to Firefox 75 or higher, then it’s probably due to this bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1628742 — which has been solved specifically for Gnome here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1635787 so it seems you got lucky and just have to wait for this fix to be included in Firefox 78 (or so it says at the bottom).

Comment: Thank you, Vej Kse! Let’s wait and see.