# Sound Volume issues Firefox Netflix 20.04

Tags: sound, firefox, pulseaudio, netflix

Thanks again to everyone for taking the time. I always get good advice here. Using Firefox with . I always have to crank up the sound volume past 100%. But after I move around a bit in Netflix the sound setting goes back to 100. This happens anytime I change anything in Netflix. Is there anyway to stop this from happening? Any assistance, most appreciated.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/1165625/968501 and https://askubuntu.com/q/1160811/968501