# Network got screwed on Ubuntu browsers

Tags: networking

To be brief, I did a `apt upgrade` on my ubuntu workstation at work and now networking in the browser is not working.

I can ping any IP (8.8.8.8, google.com, local workstations), but I can't go to any website from my browser.

I'm not 100% it's that or something else I did but the upgrade is most likely the reason.

This is what syslog has to say:

```
Mar 11 15:35:27 ws28 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[18176]: libinput error: client bug: timer event4 debounce: offset negative (-1056ms)
Mar 11 15:35:27 ws28 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[18176]: libinput error: client bug: timer event4 debounce short: offset negative (-1069ms)
Mar 11 15:35:27 ws28 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[18176]: --2021-03-11 15:35:27--  https://clients2.google.com/cr/report
Mar 11 15:35:27 ws28 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[18176]: Resolving clients2.google.com (clients2.google.com)... 142.250.186.174, 2a00:1450:4001:82b::200e
Mar 11 15:35:27 ws28 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[18176]: Connecting to clients2.google.com (clients2.google.com)|142.250.186.174|:443... libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with unknown libva error,driver_name=(null)
Mar 11 15:35:27 ws28 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[18176]: [26308:26308:0311/153527.705821:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(374)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
Mar 11 15:35:31 ws28 whoopsie[3275]: [15:35:31] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Mar 11 15:35:37 ws28 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[18176]: failed: Connection timed out.
Mar 11 15:35:37 ws28 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[18176]: Connecting to clients2.google.com (clients2.google.com)|2a00:1450:4001:82b::200e|:443... failed: Cannot assign requested address.
Mar 11 15:35:37 ws28 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[18176]: Giving up.
Mar 11 15:35:37 ws28 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[18176]: Unexpected crash report id length
Mar 11 15:35:37 ws28 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[18176]: Failed to get crash dump id.
Mar 11 15:35:37 ws28 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[18176]: Report Id:
```

Does anyone happen to have a clue on what's going on? Thanks ahead.

Comment: Which browser ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firefox 84 Crashing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1305317/firefox-84-crashing)

Comment: Looks like a DNS issue. Also, `apt upgrade` isn't the preferred way to upgrade packages. use `apt dist-upgrade` or `apt full-upgrade`.

Comment: @popey No, not at all | `full/dist-upgrade` will uninstall some packages without anyway to prevent that